# How to make a stacked bar with NA values

Tags: r, bar-chart

My data looks like this:

```
Var1 Var2 value
1      1    1    NA
2      2    1     1
3      3    1     1
4      4    1    NA
5      5    1    NA
6      6    1    NA
```

I want to make a stacked bar for "value", which shows how many `NA`, 0, 1 and 2 it has

I tried

```
barplot(data$value)
```

but that's not what I want.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
value
# [1] NA NA  2 NA  2  2  1  2 NA NA

mm <- matrix(table(value, exclude = NULL))
bb <- barplot(mm)

text(x = bb, y = cumsum(mm) - mm/2, labels = c(1, 2, "NA"), col = c("white", "black", "black"))
```

[image]